# MacOS Catalina(10.15) で Geth を実行すると 'cannot execute binary file' エラー

Tags: macos, ethereum

イーサリアムの学習のため、MacOS Catalina(10.15)に下記手順を参考に
`brew` コマンドでethereumをインストールしました。

[Gethのインストールから起動まで(Mac) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/tommo/items/912ec05eff02f7f76d30)

Gethの確認をしようとしたところ、下記のようなエラーとなってしまいました。

```
$ geth --help
-bash: /usr/local/bin/geth: cannot execute binary file
```

`brew reinstall ethereum` で再インストールしても同様の結果でした。
また、OS上の権限も問題なく実行権限が付いている状態です。

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/geth
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxxxxxx  admin  33 10 15 21:48 /usr/local/bin/geth -> ../Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin/geth
```

* xxxxxxはユーザ名です。

MacOS Mojave(10.14)ではGethの確認も問題ありませんでした。
現状Catalinaでは利用できないものでしょうか。

### 追記

file コマンドの実行結果です。

```sh
$ file /usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin/geth
/usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin/geth: data
```

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues にも挙がっていなそうなので、issue を立てると良いかもしれません。念のため `file /usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin/geth` でファイル形式を確認したものを追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: ご確認いただきありがとうございます。githubの方にissueを立ててみようと思います。またfileコマンドの結果は下記の通りバイナリファイルでした。$ file /usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin/geth
/usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin/geth: data

Comment: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ からダウンロードできるコンパイル済みの geth に対して私の手元で file コマンドを実行したところ `geth: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL>` と出力されたので、やはりインストールのどこかでおかしなことが起こっていそうです。

Comment: 確かにおしゃる通りfileステータスがexecutableではございませんでした。ご教授いただきましたURLのコンパイル済みをダウンロードしてbrewコマンドでインストールされた/usr/local/Cellar/ethereum/1.9.6/bin配下に上書きコピーして実行したところ問題なく実行できることが確認できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: それだとたとえば `brew upgrade` したときにまた同じ問題が再発しうるので、できれば問題の根本的な原因を探したいですね……。